# Ограничение на количество вводимых симоволов для команды read в bash-скрипте

Tags: bash, macos

Есть скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Укажите список файлов для прогона в одном сьюте..."
read item
SUITE="$item"
rm -f suite.txt && for i in $SUITE;  do echo $i; echo $i >>suite.txt; done;
```

Когда я запускаю его у себя локально в терминале, то текст, который я могу ввести на шаге `read`, ограничен 1115 символами. 
Скрипт используется для того, чтобы записать в файл название тестов в формате `/Path_to_file/TestClassName.php` поэтому данное ограничение на ввод довольно критично.
Попробовал запускать тот же скрипт на удаленной машине под управлением линукс, там этой проблемы нет, то есть, как я понимаю, ограничение именно на моей машине (Macos Catalina 10.15.3).
Как можно убрать или увеличить лимит в 1115 символов?

Comment: Очень странно. У меня нет под рукой macOS, проверить не могу, но в исходниках bash нет никаких ограничений. Они просто по мере необходимости увеличивают внутренний буфер на 128 байт: https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_bash/blob/bc007799f0e1362100375bb95d952d28de4c62fb/builtins/read.def#L622

Comment: @PakUula мне думается это ограничение самого терминала, но макоси у меня тоже нет, проверить не могу

Comment: @perguunt, чтобы проверить предположение @PotroNik, запустите скрипт с чтением из файла. Что будет, если строку длиной более 1115 байт записать в файл `suite.txt` и выполнить команду `cat suite.txt | bash your_script.sh` ?

Comment: @PakUula если строку бОльшей длины записать в файл и выполнить команду, то все в порядке и такого ограничения нет, то есть ограничение действительно где-то в настройках самого терминала. Проверил в iTerm и Терминал - ограничение есть и там, и там.
Кроме того похоже, что я в первый раз неверно определил длину ограничения. Сейчас перепроверил ограничение равно 1024 символам.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7140575/4827341

Comment: В режиме работы `bash` по стандарту `POSIX` перехватываемые сигналы могут прерывать выполнение `read`, в таком случае команда возвращает значение __128__ плюс номер сигнала, частично отвергнув прочитанные входные данные. Длина, если не изменяет память, задается -n или -N, в обоих случаях читается заданное количество байтов, однако в первом случае чтение прервется при встрече символа разделителя, во втором, напротив, символ разделитель будет включен в считанные данные.